# ZF2 How to get unloaded config file in controller?

Tags: zend-framework2, multiple-databases, on-the-fly

**The cenario**
My application is divided by many agencies, each one with it's own database and database configuration file.

Before logging in, the user needs to send me an `agency-id`. In that request ZF2 load a non-agency db configutarion file (with SQLite database info) to validate if `agency-id` really exists.

The next requests are made to `agency-specific-url` so ZF2 load that agency's specific db configutarion file.

**The problem**
In the first request (to validate `agency-id`) after I validate it, I need to load the agency's specific database to fetch some info and return it.

I was thinking of loading that *"unloaded agency database config file"* in my `controller`, to instantiate a `model` with a `DbAdapter` containing the agency's database info for that, but I can't find a way to do it.

How can I do this or is there another way? Perhaps I should load every agency config file before ZF2's init but I don't know if that's the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I created an action that will return the agency's info.
Inside the agency-id validate action, create a request for the above action and get it's response:

```
// Create request to get agency's info
$client   = new Client();
$request  = new Request();
$request->setMethod(Request::METHOD_GET);
$explicitUrl = 'http://example.com/any/action';
$request->setUri($explicitUrl);
$response = $client->send($request);

// The any/action route points to an action that return JSON data
$json     = JsonDecoder::decode($response->getBody());

// Now I can do whatenever I want
$json->variable1...
$json->variable2...
$json->variable3...
```